# Display all possible solutions in ojAlgo

Tags: constraint-programming, ojalgo

**Question:** Is it possible to adjust the above to produce all possible results instead of an optimized one.

**Details:** Given a data set of armor, I want to produce a set of combinations where my constraints are fulfilled.

```
    Variable helm1 = model.addVariable("Helm 1").binary();
    Variable helm2 = model.addVariable("Helm 2").binary();
    Variable helm3 = model.addVariable("Helm 3").binary();

    Variable arm1 = model.addVariable("Arm 1").binary();
    Variable arm2 = model.addVariable("Arm 2").binary();
    Variable arm3 = model.addVariable("Arm 3").binary();

    Expression statA = model.addExpression().lower(0).weight(1);
    Expression statB = model.addExpression().lower(0).weight(1);
    Expression statC = model.addExpression().lower(0).weight(1);
    //Lower Limit set for desired stat
    Expression statD = model.addExpression().lower(2).weight(1); 

    // Limit number of helms you can equip
    model.addExpression().upper(1).set(helm1,1).set(helm2,1).set(helm3,1);
    model.addExpression().upper(1).set(arm1,1).set(arm2,1).set(arm3,1);

    statA.set(arm1, 1);

    statB.set(helm2, 1);
    statB.set(helm3, 1);
    statB.set(arm2, 1);

    statC.set(helm1, 1);
    statC.set(arm2, 1);
    statC.set(arm3, 1);

    statD.set(helm3, 3);
    statD.set(arm1, 1);
    Optimisation.Result result = model.maximise();
    BasicLogger.debug(result);
```

**Note:** Before recommending libraries, please not that the library must be compatible with Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer**: No - ojAlgo will output 1 (the optimal if it can find it) solution.

Comment: Thank you. Though I prefer ojAlgo's API, I've opted to use Choco-solver 3.3.3.